# ReactNative- Tab Navigator Inside Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

Need to Show Tabs For Home Module after Signup Module
using React-navigation

Working Code with Only Stack Screens

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Bottom = createBottomTabNavigator();
render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
              <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Welcome" headerMode='none' >
                <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} 
                    options={{
                        title: '',
                        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
                        headerBackTitle: '',
                        headerShown: true
                      }}
                 />
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPasswordScreen} />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          );
    }
```

Need to show Tab from SigninScreen Button
Tab 1: Dashboard: 
Tab 2: Profile

Tried Code:

```
<Bottom.Navigator initialRouteName="Dashboard" >
                        <Bottom.Screen name="Dashboard" component={TabDashboard} />
                        <Bottom.Screen name="Profile" component={TabProfile} />
                    </Bottom.Navigator>
```

Now I need to combine these two block of codes so I can navigate to Tabs
Tab screen will have further navigations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea would be to wrap the tabs screen inside component and add it to the stack conditionally.

```
const HomeScreen = () =>{
 return (
   <Bottom.Navigator initialRouteName="Dashboard" >
    <Bottom.Screen name="Dashboard" component={TabDashboard} />
     <Bottom.Screen name="Profile" component={TabProfile} />
   </Bottom.Navigator>
 );
}
```

Your stack should change as below

```
render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
              <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Welcome" headerMode='none' >
                  {
                      this.state.isSignedIn ? (
                        <>
                          <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
                          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
                          <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} />
                          <Stack.Screen name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPasswordScreen} />
                        </>
                       ) : (
                        <>
                          <Stack.Screen name="ResetPassword" component={HomeScreen} />
                        </>
                       )
                  }
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          );
    }
```

IsSignedIn can be the state variable or a variable that you store the logged in status

You can refer the authentication flows
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow

Comment: Getting Error: Error: Creating a navigator doesn't take an argument. Maybe you are trying to use React Navigation 4 API with React Navigation 5? See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x for migration guide.

Comment: Great, you are welcome :) also please mark the answer if its correct